# there are a better solutions to set FIELDS as data at ADODB query from xls file (exported from SAP)

Tags: sql, adodb

My excel program import from another workbook, exported from SAP, some columns to update my dashboard.

To do this I use ADODB, the code run right and fast (26K rows and 32 columns on 00:00:26:1226).

But I see that some columns with data/time aren't correctly formatted, the poblem is that not all date columns just some, I think are a Sap problem, but i get this file from customer and it will my problem.

[image]

So, this are my query without any custom format, just extraction:

```
cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & WsFrom.FullName & "; Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;"";"

SELECT '1.1' as IdKpi, [(06)-Data creazione]*1 as DateCreation,  '' as Divisione, 
[(01-A)-Ordine d'acquisto] as Orders, 
switch([(07)D-Modalità Trasp] = 'AOG','AOG',
[(07)D-Modalità Trasp] <> 'AOG','STD') as Trasporto,
[(07)-Fine carico att] as StartDateSap, 
[(07)-Ora attfine car] as StartTimeSap, 
[(01-A)-Data di reg] as EndDateSap, [(01-A)-Ora di acquisizione] as EndTimeSap, 
[(07)-Inizio trasp att] as StartDateBlock, 
[(07)-Ora attinizio trasp] as StartTimeBlock, 
[(07)-Data FINE Sdoganamento] as EndDateBlock, 
[(07-A)-Sdogan-Fine-EffOra] as EndTimeBlock, 
[(02)-Utente] as Users, [(06-A)-Blocco-In-Data] as DateBlockIn, 
[(07)-Tipo di trasporto] as DoganaTax1, 
[(09-A)-Controllo conferma] as DoganaTax2,
from [Sheet1$];

rs.Open strsql, cn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText
rs.MoveFirst
dbSh.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
```

this is the 1th test, I updated code (I change [data/time_Field] as customName to Cdate([data/time_Field]) as customName. 
the update show me all data/time fields like as data/time the qry run on 00:01:08:128

```
cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & WsFrom.FullName & "; Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;"";"

SELECT '1.1' as IdKpi, [(06)-Data creazione]*1 as DateCreation,  '' as Divisione, 
[(01-A)-Ordine d'acquisto] as Orders, 
switch([(07)D-Modalità Trasp] = 'AOG','AOG',
[(07)D-Modalità Trasp] <> 'AOG','STD') as Trasporto,
[(07)-Fine carico att]*1 as StartDateSap, 
[(07)-Ora attfine car] as StartTimeSap, 
[(01-A)-Data di reg]*1 as EndDateSap, [(01-A)-Ora di acquisizione] as EndTimeSap, 
[(07)-Inizio trasp att]*1 as StartDateBlock, 
[(07)-Ora attinizio trasp] as StartTimeBlock, 
[(07)-Data FINE Sdoganamento]*1 as EndDateBlock, 
[(07-A)-Sdogan-Fine-EffOra] as EndTimeBlock, 
[(02)-Utente] as Users, [(06-A)-Blocco-In-Data]*1 as DateBlockIn, 
[(07)-Tipo di trasporto]*1 as DoganaTax1, 
[(09-A)-Controllo conferma]*1 as DoganaTax2,
from [Sheet1$];

rs.Open strsql, cn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText
rs.MoveFirst
dbSh.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
```

this is the 2th test, I updated code (I change [data/time_Field] as customName to [data/time_Field]*1 as customName. 
the update show me all date fields like as data/time the qry run on 00:00:44:1244

```
cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & WsFrom.FullName & "; Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;"";"

SELECT '1.1' as IdKpi, [(06)-Data creazione]*1 as DateCreation,  '' as Divisione, 
[(01-A)-Ordine d'acquisto] as Orders, 
switch([(07)D-Modalità Trasp] = 'AOG','AOG',
[(07)D-Modalità Trasp] <> 'AOG','STD') as Trasporto,
[(07)-Fine carico att]*1 as StartDateSap, 
[(07)-Ora attfine car] as StartTimeSap, 
[(01-A)-Data di reg]*1 as EndDateSap, [(01-A)-Ora di acquisizione] as EndTimeSap, 
[(07)-Inizio trasp att]*1 as StartDateBlock, 
[(07)-Ora attinizio trasp] as StartTimeBlock, 
[(07)-Data FINE Sdoganamento]*1 as EndDateBlock, 
[(07-A)-Sdogan-Fine-EffOra] as EndTimeBlock, 
[(02)-Utente] as Users, [(06-A)-Blocco-In-Data]*1 as DateBlockIn, 
[(07)-Tipo di trasporto]*1 as DoganaTax1, 
[(09-A)-Controllo conferma]*1 as DoganaTax2,
from [Sheet1$];

rs.Open strsql, cn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText
rs.MoveFirst
dbSh.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
```

So, my workaround work fine, for me is slow and I'm not sure that is a good code, there are a better way?